# How to compact SQL instructions in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage

I'm making a tiny app that will use Databases, I want to know how to convert this:

```
function testDB()
{
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "mydatabase", 2000000);
    db.transaction(queryNames, errorDB);
}
function queryNames(tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql('SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=13', [], listNames, errorDB);
}
function listNames(tx, results) 
{
    for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++)
    {
        alert(results.rows.item(i).name);
    }
}
function errorDB(err)
{
    alert("Fatal error");
}
```

To something like this (either if it is possible more compacted):

```
function testDB()
{
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "mydatabase", 2000000);
    db.transaction(queryNames('SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=13'), errorDB);
}
function queryNames(tx, query) 
{
    tx.executeSql(, [], 
    function listNames(tx, results) 
    {
        for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++)
        {
            alert(results.rows.item(i).name);
        }
    },
    errorDB);
}
function errorDB(err)
{
    alert("Fatal error");
}
```

In few words, I'm trying to "recycle" the code. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does your code work as it is now?  The reason I ask is because it looks like your `queryNames` takes the transaction as its first parameter, but when you call it, you are passing a string.  Once I know this, I can help you out.

Comment: @Jrd the first example works, the second no, is a kind of example of how I want to reduce, I don't know how to recycle the code, I want to pass the SQL as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite call is an event. I have created the following function by using jQuery (The function is also logging the results in the console, so you need the console plugin for working):

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "mydatabase", 2000000);

function queryDB(query) {

    var start    = Date.now();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results) {
            console.log("Rows: " + results.rows.length + " Time: " + (Date.now() - start) + "ms Query: " + query);
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Error processing SQL: " + error.code + " " + error.no + " Query: " + query);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Transaction Error: " + error.code + " " + error.no + " Query: " + query);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

And the function call is:

```
$.when(queryDB("SELECT * FROM table")).done(function (results) {
        // Here your logic with the results
});
```

The advantage of this way is, that you can call multiple queries the same time:

```
$.when(queryDB("SELECT * FROM table1"), queryDB("SELECT * FROM table2")).done(function (results1, results2) {
        // Here your logic with the results
});
```

Comment: Wow, it looks nice, I will try it!

Comment: Perfect +1, but please, explain me what is `when` and `deferred`.

Comment: Thx for upvoting. Deferred is a way to «collect» callbacks. Have a look at the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ and https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would suggest.  Make a separate database object that just has a generic query method.  That way, you can reuse it from anywhere else in your application.  Something like the following:

Here's the database object:

```
var DB = function () {
    this.db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "mydatabase", 2000000);
};

DB.prototype.error = function () {
    alert("Fatal Error");
};

DB.prototype.query = function (query, callback) {
    this.db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results) {
            callback(results);
        });
    }, this.error); 
};
```

And now you can call it to do your names query like so:

```
var myDB = new DB();
var namesQuery = 'SELECT name FROM people WHERE id=13';

myDB.query(namesQuery, function (results) {
    for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++) {
        alert(results.rows.item(i).name);
    }
});
```

This is just a basic example.  You would probably want to add extra stuff for error handling/named arguments/etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Which is the command to invoke the function? I mean the equivalent of `testDB();` so I can call it to test your code.

Comment: The code in the second block is what would test it.  If you want, you could wrap all of that in a `testDB` function and call it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: My debugger thorws an error in another JavaScript library, I will try to find out the issue.