# disable async db call in ionic cordova

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using this code to get data from database. but it always prints the result of this line  `console.log('outside ret data ' + retData);` as undefined/null. because `$cordovaSQLite.execute` is an async call. How can i stop this until i get the result in the  `retData` object. Please help

**Code:**

```
var retData = [];

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM suppliertypes", []).then(function (res) {
     console.log("total rows found: " + res.rows.length);
     retData = res;

   }, function (err) {
            console.log("Error looking up Supplier types: " + err);
 });

console.log('outside ret data ' + retData);
return retData;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this answer. It makes use of Promise object.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31869081/5336859

Link to [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)