# Apache Cordova using SQLite - Can't wait to return data

Tags: sqlite, cordova

```
     function outDb(outData) {
         var temp;
         var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "test" });
         db.executeSql("SELECT " + outData + " FROM test", [], function (res) {
             switch (outData) {
                       case "goal": temp = res.rows.item(0).GOAL;
                     break;
                 case "curDate":  temp = res.rows.item(0).CURDATE;
                     break;
                 case "Day1":  temp = res.rows.item(0).DAY1;
                     break;
                 case "Day2":  temp = res.rows.item(0).DAY2;
                     break;
                 case "Day3":  temp = res.rows.item(0).DAY3;
                     break;
                 default: temp = "is default";
             }
         });
         return temp;
     }
```

I want to save data into myData;

```
var myData = outDb("goal");
```

But this is not working, because the `return` statement happens faster than the data is assigned to my variable.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use callback function because Cordova-sqlite-storage works asynchronously.

```
function getFromDB(_n, fn) {
var db = ...
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <field_name> = ?";
    tx.executeSql(query, [_n], function (tx, rs) {
        for(var x = 0; x < rs.rows.length; x++) {
            _res = rs.rows.item(x).value;
            fn(_res);
        }
    }, function (tx, error) {
        console.log('select error: ' + error.message);
    });
}, function (error) {
    console.log('transaction error: ' + error.message);
}, function () {
    console.log('transaction ok.');
});}

getFromDB(<name>, function(val) {
console.log(val);});
```

Answer (score 0):

All sqlite commands are event driven. That means, that you have to wait for values until the event is finished.

In your case: You will never get a return value, because your return is outside of the success function.

You could do a rewrite of your function like:

```js
function outDb(outData) {
     var temp;
     var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "test" });
     db.executeSql("SELECT " + outData + " FROM test", [], function (res) {
         switch (outData) {
                   case "goal": temp = res.rows.item(0).GOAL;
                 break;
             case "curDate":  temp = res.rows.item(0).CURDATE;
                 break;
             case "Day1":  temp = res.rows.item(0).DAY1;
                 break;
             case "Day2":  temp = res.rows.item(0).DAY2;
                 break;
             case "Day3":  temp = res.rows.item(0).DAY3;
                 break;
             default: temp = "is default";
         }
         return temp;
     });
    
 }
```

A much better way is like I showed in this answer:

[How to compact SQL instructions in Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866603/how-to-compact-sql-instructions-in-cordova/31869081#31869081)