# How to create a database to store logs using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, database, cordova, phonegap-build

I am dsigning an app for iOS using phonegap. What I want to do is log down the date and time each time when the user pressed a button on the screen, and be able to view the log on device screen with an admin access. I know I have to create some sort of a database to store the info, but can someone give me an example on how to create one as I'm new to phonegap and not sure how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need a client side browser database. What are my options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777968/i-need-a-client-side-browser-database-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best SQLite Plugin for saving a lot of data is this plugin:

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

There is no limit of storing. In this post [How to compact SQL instructions in Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866603/how-to-compact-sql-instructions-in-cordova/31869081#31869081) I have written how to compact SQLite instructions, so you have not all this event overload.

But do you really want save every tap? That will be a lot of scripting work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as localStorage would be sufficient for your problem. You can simlply Json.stringify your data and put it to the local storage. Later get it from there and json.parse it. No phonegap needed just pure html5. Try search for localstorage HTM5

Comment: Localstorage can only store 5MB of data as I heard. I want something that can store more than that.