# SQLite plugin Cordova basic code

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins

I'm new to Cordova & Sqlite but I wrote some code and I can't figure out what is wrong with it? Any suggestions? 
I always get the following output from the Javascript debugger:

[Click to see error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zELSD.png)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    var output = document.getElementById('outputField');

    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'test.db', location: 2 }, function (db) {
            output.innerHTML += '</br> - Database created/opened';

            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(tx, "CREATE TABLE  localStorage2 IF NOT EXISTS (key UNIQUE, value)");
            });


            output.innerHTML += '</br> - Table localStorage2 Created';

            storeValue(db, 'localStorage2', 'testKey', 'testValue');
            output.innerHTML += '</br> - Insert dummy value';

            output.innerHTML += '</br> ' + readValue(db, 'localStorage2', 'testKey');
        });
    }


    function storeValue(db, table, key, value) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(tx, 'INSERT INTO ' + table + ' (key,value) VALUES ("' + key + '","' + value + '")');
        });

    }

    function readValue(db, table, key) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            return db.executeSql(tx, 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE key="' + key + '"');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you used any plugin for SQLite? If yes, then you can also use SQLite without any plugin. Check link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879785/cordova-sqlite-plugin-not-functioning-with-android-studio/33894275#33894275

Comment: Please read the docs here: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage Your main problem is, that your code is not event driven. You can't use return values in event driven scripts.

Comment: @Dhruv I use SQLite plugin described by Joerg

Comment: @Joerg What do you mean by event driven? Can you give a little example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing a new plugin, library, … whatever, the best way is to read the docs, play a little bit with the examples and expand it step by step for your needs.

The SQLite plugin is event driven, that means, that you have to wait until the job is done.

You are doing it this way and this **don't** work:

```
var the_result = mySQL_Job();

function mySQL_Job(){
   db.readTransaction(function(tx) {   
      return db.executeSql(…);
   });
}
```

The right way is:

```
mySQL_Job();

function mySQL_Job(some_values){
   tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM myTable", [], function(tx, res) {

      //Here goes your result handling, like inserting values in your html

}, function(error) {
    console.log('SQLite error: ' + error.message);
  });
}
```

This you have to do for every sql job, please see the docs at: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

If you have a lot of queries then it is a good idea to use promises: [How to compact SQL instructions in Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866603/how-to-compact-sql-instructions-in-cordova/31869081#31869081)